# JMeter Script Development

Tags: performance, jmeter, jmeter-4.0, script-debugging

Can I use Blazemeter extension for script recording. It's says free version. I know it's free and easy to record but at the same time i don't want to take any risks in future as well. Please suggest me wheather it's correct approach or not?

Scripts Development blazemeter extension
Scripts Execution Non GUI mode command line

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the optimal recording and development solution, I would recommend Octoperf.  And yes, you can export the solution for use in standard Jmeter.

Octoperf has taken a different tack from a Blazemeter or Flood.IO.   They have attacked the creation and maintenance challenge in addition to the run-at-load challenge.  They have built something elegant and distinct for building and maintaining scripts for JMeter.

Editorial note:  I don't work for Octoperf.  They don't pay me to speak on their behalf.  I just think they have the best solution for building and maintaining scripts on the Jmeter front.